# Integrating xUnit/nUnit Tests with Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, xunit, microsoft-test-manager

The company I'm working at uses xUnit to write Integration tests. xUnit works perfectly for us but we will like to extract more statistical information out of runs. For example - "How many times did this specific Test-Case has been failing in the last month", and maybe even sort it out nicely on a pie chart.

Since we have a Microsoft Test Manager license, I did some research on it, and it seems like it does support more detailed reports. I also like the coupling between Manual Test-Cases to Automation Test-Cases, and the fact you easily identify how much of your Test-Cases are automated.

Sadly enough, Test Manager only support MSTest integration out of the box. I did noticed however that the MSTest.ext alternative - VSTest.exe is able to run xUnit tests, and even output TRX result file. Is there any way to integrate xUnit (or nUnit) to the Test Manager somehow? Has anyone done so in the past? we prefer to use Test Manager, but I'm interesting to know if there is an alternative that support a couple Test-Cases with Automated Test-Cases and a way to get statistical information about multiple-runs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool will allow you to associate NUnit and xUnit test cases with Microsoft Test Manager.

https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/TestCaseAutomationAssigner

Comment: Thank you! It's no longer relevant for me, but I'm sure this will be great for other people :-)

Answer (score 1):

After some research on the Microsoft Forum (and personally speaking with Microsoft representative), It seems like it's not possible to use xUnit with MS Test Manager.

We decided not to use MS Test Manager and handle all our test runs using VSTest.exe and xUnit categories.

Edit: It's now possible to use an external tool for that called "TestCaseAutomationAssigner". See Jeff's answer for more information.